# How to add role and Users in asp.net mvc 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I want to add User authorization and authentication in asp.net mvc project. I am Entity Framework Code First. Now I want to create some default user and default role for it. For this I want to create a Admin Role, but it is preventing me that User and Role Named admin and Admin Exists already. But when I see in my Database Table such as AspNetUSers , Role etc. there I did not find any named Admin. So how can I do this?

If the admin role and users are built in, so where is the password. And also how can I create some other default users and roles each time when my application is running first.

I am using MVC 5 ,not mvc 4. There are difference for both of these two.

Thanks,

Abdus Salam Azad

Comment: Check this project : https://github.com/rustd/AspnetIdentitySample

Answer (score 5):

Since no one ever answered your question, I though I would add some code that shows how to do this from the Seed method on a migration. This code is used to seed an initial user in the database with an admin role. In my case, only the 'admin' user can add new users to the site.

```
protected override void Seed(PerSoft.Marketing.Website.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    const string defaultRole = "admin";
    const string defaultUser = "someUser";

    // This check for the role before attempting to add it.
    if (!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == defaultRole))
    {
        context.Roles.Add(new IdentityRole(defaultRole));
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    // This check for the user before adding them.
    if (!context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == defaultUser))
    {
        var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = defaultUser };
        manager.Create(user, "somePassword");

        manager.AddToRole(user.Id, defaultRole);
    }
    else
    {
        // Just for good measure, this adds the user to the role if they already
        // existed and just weren't in the role.
        var user = context.Users.Single(u => u.UserName.Equals(defaultUser, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
        var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
        manager.AddToRole(user.Id, defaultRole);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use this method, the IdentityUserRoles table in the db only has values in two (of its four) fields. If I don't get all 4 fields populated then some other (built-in) code fails. Any ideas on this?