# How to programmatically create users in asp.net 5 using identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I´m trying to create some users in a seed method, but no luck.

I had used this example: [How to add role and Users in asp.net mvc 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22801862/how-to-add-role-and-users-in-asp-net-mvc-5) but the `UserManager` seams to be instantiate in a different way.

Looking in the `AccountController`, this instance is loaded in the constructor:

```
    public AccountController(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
        IEmailSender emailSender,
        ISmsSender smsSender,
        BennerCliContext applicationDbContext)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _emailSender = emailSender;
        _smsSender = smsSender;
        _applicationDbContext = applicationDbContext;
    }
```

But my seed method lies on the `MyDbContext` class.

How can I access the `UserManager` instance from there?

There are another ways to create users in vnext ?

### update

After @Vladislav Karamfilov suggestion:

[image]

Comment: Hey did you manage to resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since user manager already had been registered in ASP.NET5's service provider you could easily get instance of user manager by calling following method:

```
 var userManager=new HttpContextAccessor()
     .HttpContext.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(UserManager<ApplicationUser>));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create an instance of `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` and then use the `CreateIdentity` method to create an `ApplicationUser` object. However if you assign Administrator role to the created user and your code is public be really careful **not to expose your site's security**.

Comment: Like this? It´s stange:
var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store, null, null, null, null,null,null,null,null,null);

Comment: `var store = new UserStore<User>(context);
 var manager = new UserManager<User>(store);
 var user = new User(username, "sample@mail.com");

 manager.Create(user, password);`

Comment: But I can´t instantiate a UserManager like this. Look at my update.

Comment: Which version of Identity do you use?

Comment: it is identity 2.0, I guess. I´m using vs2015 with asp.net 5 (mvc 6)

Comment: I see... My solution is for the old version - ASP.NET MVC 5 and Identity 2. So far I haven't played with the new ASP.NET MVC 6 and the new Identity system so I can't provide a solution. Maybe later today or tomorrow I can set up a solution to test your case if no answer is given by then...